# Compare two files in Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a problem when comparing two files, which I do by using the command:

```
diff file1.csv file2.csv >> outputfile.csv
```

Everything works correctly. The problem is, if there's a line missing in one of them, my IDs start to differ/are no longer the same and everything is shifted, so `diff` returns every line after the shift.

How can I remedy this problem?

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: that image shows that not only was one row deleted but ***also*** all lines (from the point of deletion) were also renumbered/modified hence the reason a `diff` is going to show all of the rows as different (ie, because all of the rows *have been* modified)

Comment: Removing the "id" line from both files before doing the diff is the obvious approach.

Answer (score 1):

Skip the ID column when doing the comparison. You can use process substitution for this.

```
diff <(cut -d, -f2- file1.csv) <(cut -d, -f2- file2.csv)
```

Comment: It's ok but if i want to keep the ID in my output file, how i do that ?

Comment: Are the IDs always sequential line numbers? `diff` shows the line numbers of the differences.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346483/compare-two-files-ignoring-1st-column-and-print-line-number